# Declare variables in controller symfony2

Tags: variables, symfony, controllers

I have one doubt, I know the (Symfony2) controller's function and so I think is not correct to declare variables inside of these classes. **But is possible?**

In this way I could have one variable in all methods keeping its state.

Thanks.

Comment: That's the convention, so yes, it's perfectly right to do the logic within a controller.

Comment: Thanks you too. As in most examples I had not seen declare variables inside of Controllers I had not clear this question. But for concepts I supposed that it could be correct. Thanks to all for clear my mind!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is **possible** and correct.